Can validation results for attribute-based validations be merged with ones for custom validations?
When there are multiple invalid properties that are decorated with data annotations and validated with custom validation, I want to obtain validation results for all the invalid properties rather than just the first invalid one (as what is produced by the following code).
using MiniValidation;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

var widget = new Widget { Name = "A", Age = 0 };

if (!MiniValidator.TryValidate(widget, out var errors))
{
    foreach (var entry in errors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"  {entry.Key}:");
        foreach (var error in entry.Value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"  - {error}");
        }
    }
}

class Widget : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required, MinLength(3)] 
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext ctx)
    {
        if (Age < 10)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Age cannot be less than 10.", [nameof(Age)]);
    }
}


I don't want to replace the attribute-based validations with  custom validation.
class Widget : IValidatableObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext ctx)
    {
        if (Name is null)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Name must be specified.", [nameof(Name)]);
        if (Name?.Length < 3)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Name must contain at least 3 characters.", [nameof(Name)]);


        if (Age < 10)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Age cannot be less than 10.", [nameof(Age)]);
    }
}



I'd actually recommend replacing both with FluentValidation, but I guess that's off the table... what exactly is "MiniValidation" though? Never heard of that.

If it is this: https://github.com/DamianEdwards/MiniValidation then the readme suggests you can do this by inheritance. Have a base with annotations and derived with custom validation.

@Fildor: No difference with inheritance. Only the first validation result is returned.

I'll give it a try later today. I actually think the library should perform all possible validation variations. Not really a bug but that would be much more convenient.

Reproduction of the behavior: https://dotnetfiddle.net/49r9L4 ... next is to try and fix it.

Inheritance doesn't fix, indeed : https://dotnetfiddle.net/WtvzwZ - I also wonder why the same output is written twice ... maybe it's me. All-in-all I would grade the nuget "pre-production" at best. So my recommendation is to fall back to dotnet-on-board tools and/or roll your own or as said in the beginning use FluentValidation (or something similarly mature).

Apparently this issue has been discussed here: https://github.com/DamianEdwards/MiniValidation/issues/34

On the fly I came up with this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RKCgFR - maybe it helps?

I was able to reproduce the observed behavior and I was actually mistaken about the behavior when inheriting from an annotated class.
(talking about the comment "If it is this: github.com/DamianEdwards/MiniValidation then the readme suggests you can do this by inheritance. Have a base with annotations and derived with custom validation." )
Outside providing a feature to that project, I see these remedies:

Switch to FluentValidation or a similar more mature tooling.
Roll your own along the lines of this poc:

using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var widget = new Widget
        {
            Name = "A",
            Age = 0
        };
        
        if (!MyValidator.TryValidate(widget, out var myErrors))
        {
            foreach( var (name, error) in myErrors )
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{name} :");
                foreach( var msg in error )
                    Console.WriteLine($"    - {msg}");
            }
        }
    }
}

static class MyValidator
{
    public record MyResult(string Name, IReadOnlyCollection<string> Errors);
    
    public static bool TryValidate<T>(T obj, out IEnumerable<MyResult> errors)
    {
        var ctx = new ValidationContext(obj);
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        if (obj is IValidatableObject ivo)
        {
            results.AddRange(ivo.Validate(ctx));
        }
        
        var validatorResult = Validator.TryValidateObject(obj, ctx, results, true);
        
        if (!validatorResult || results.Any())
        {
            errors = results.SelectMany(r => r.MemberNames.Select(n => new {Name = n, Error = r.ErrorMessage}))
                .GroupBy(o => o.Name)
                .Select(grp => new MyResult(grp.Key, grp.Select(o => o.Error).ToList()))
                .ToList();
                            
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            errors = [];
            return true;
        }
    }
}

class Widget : IValidatableObject
{
    
    [Required, MinLength(3)]
    public string Name { get; set; } = null !;
    [Range(10, 1000, 
        ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be between {1} and {2}.")]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext ctx)
    {
        if (Age < 10)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Age cannot be less than 10.", [nameof(Age)]);
    }
}

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5FUcEo
Output:

Age :
    - Age cannot be less than 10.
    - Value for Age must be between 10 and 1000.
Name :
    - The field Name must be a string or array type with a minimum length of '3'.

Disclaimer: I do not consider above code "production ready". It is supposed to briefly showcase a possible first step towards a solid solution.
